# Import sql syntax, Windows SQL Server and Apache Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

I have below sql export from `Microsoft SQL Sever` and I tried to import into `Mysql` running by `Apache` in osx. I got an Sql syntax error from line 1. I am new and I actually have never seen the sql using `[ ]` as quote fot string.

- May I ask is the sql different from Sql Server in Windows and the
  Mysql in Apache?
- If I want to import below database into mysql, what should I check
  and look at?

Thank you very much for your adverses!!

Best regards,

```
USE [boatexpress]
GO
/****** Object:  Schema [boatexpress]    Script Date: 07/22/2013 14:15:07 ******/
CREATE SCHEMA [boatexpress] AUTHORIZATION [boatexpress]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[waybill111]    Script Date: 07/22/2013 14:15:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[waybill111](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [slAAECode] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [slProductName] [ntext] NULL,
    [slRecName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [slRecMobi] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [slRecAddress] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [slZipCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [slweight] [float] NULL,
    [ktype] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [worth] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [adminid] [int] NULL,
    [addtime] [date] NULL,
    [insurance] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_waybill] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax from SQL to MySQL is different. If you want to create above table use this syntax.

Create the database

```
CREATE SCHEMA `boatexpress` ;
```

Create the table

```
CREATE TABLE boatexpress.waybill111 (
    `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `slAAECode` nvarchar(100) NULL,
    `slProductName` text NULL,
    `slRecName` nvarchar(50) NULL,
    `slRecMobi` nvarchar(50) NULL,
    `slRecAddress` nvarchar (255) NULL,
    `slZipCode` nvarchar(50) NULL,
    `slweight` float NULL,
    `ktype` nvarchar(50) NULL,
    `worth` nvarchar(150) NULL,
    `adminid` int NULL,
    `addtime` date NULL,
    `insurance` nvarchar(50) NULL);
```

Datatypes like ntext doesnt exists in MySQL. I just renamed it to `TEXT`. Also `[]` are not used to wrap columns but ` is. For datatypes you dont need to enclose them at all.

Is this what you are looking for?

**Also, your SQL code is actually trying to use boatexpress before creating it.**